# How to better include type declarations

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have type declarations in separate files (currently `d.ts`).

With having those files in `include` section of `tsconfig.json` I have those types available globally in my app, which is fine.

Another way of including types (I saw more often) is to actually export types from `ts` files and import them to the places of usage. It should work but I wanted to share some common types between many modules.

Besides my module system is not perfect, what's the difference between using `d.ts` and `ts` files for sharing types between modules in the app? What are the drawbacks of using `d.ts` and polluting the global namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Declaration files are usually generated from a JavaScript package so we can have types when using it in TypeScript. I've personally never written a declaration file in my TS projects, the only exception being when I need to [merge declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).